# Charting. How to add DateTime point to another series?

Tags: c#, charts

I have C# 4.7 WinForms application using charting. I've successfully bound List to chart of type line. I'm trying to place some points of type DateTime above current graph.

Series1 is my chart with DataSource = List. X = DateTime, Y = Value.

After DataBindXY points looks like {X=38554.1666666667, Y=1227.040039}

I've created another Series2 of type point to place point above. 
How to convert DateTime to value like 38554.1666666667?

```
chart1.DataSource = list;
chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Date";
chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Value";
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(list, "Date", list, "Value");

Series new_vals = new Series();
new_vals.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
new_vals.Points.AddXY(38575.1666666667, 1237.810059);
chart1.Series.Add(new_vals);
```

Comment: Add the new value to the variable list.

Comment: There are conversion functions for that: [DateTime.ToOADate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [DateTime.FromOADate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Did you set the series.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime; ?

Comment: TaW, Thanks, FromOADate works. I didn't set XValueType.